# Express with CORS doesn't block all requests

Tags: javascript, express, curl, networking, cors

I'm currently learning how to use Express. One thing that I can't wrap my head around is the fact why my initialization code of Express doesn't lead to an error for each request since my CORS setup is indicating that no CORS requests should be allowed in the first place.

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
    origin: false,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.json({a:10})
}

app.listen(8080,function() {
    console.log("Express is listening on port 8080")
}
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Because whenever I do a CORS request via curl by issuing the following command:

```
curl -H "Origin: http://toto.com" -H "Host: http://toto.com" http://localhost:80/
```

the route handler is fired and I get the json response {a: 10}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS protection is handled IN the browser. Any server side or curl request will just do fine.

CORS stands for Cross Origin Resource Sharing. In short, there is no "origin" when requesting from a server (or curl).

[edit]
CORS will protect your domain (let's say example.com) from any requests being made in the browser from another domain (let's say foobar.com).

If foorbar.com becomes compromised, let's say by injecting some javascript in a page. And someone tries to fire an AJAX request (on your behalf) to example.com (on which you are admin). Some attacker might get information about example.com.  CORS will protect that.

This is just an example, but CORS will also protect your assets like css, images, javascript from being loaded from another domain.

Comment: More accurately, [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) protection is handled in the browser. CORS is a mechanism for telling the browser to relax the policy.

Answer (score -1):

CORS is a mechanism, used by browsers to deny malicious AJAX requests. This is done by asking the server first which origins should be able to send requests, and what kind of requests are allowed from such origins. Then, the browser will check what the origin of the request is, and if the origin is not allowed, the request won't be sent.

The server is NOT responsible for handling invalid origins, and will happily process any requests, regardless of origin. In your case, I believe its something to do with `curl`. It might not be actually intercepting the request. Use your browser to test such request, either trough the developer menu, or via any of the countless online tools for making HTTP requests.